# How can I make .bat file to open multiple files in its default application by python?

Tags: python, batch-file, python-3.6

I am new here in stackOverflow. I have just start learning python. I have to make `.bat` file to open multiple files in its default application (teradyne software).

Can anyone help me through my program. I have already written list of all the files in the `.bat` file. Whenever I run `.bat` file, the application still asks me to select files.

```
App_path = r"C:\Program Files\Teradyne\IG-XL\5.10.55_flx\bin"
f = open("H:\\list2.bat","a")
f.writelines(App_path)
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(src):
    for file in files:
        list = os.path.join(root,file) #makes list of files with directory
        f.writelines("%s \n" %list)  
        #print(list)                  
f.close()               
os.system("H:\\list2.bat")
```

Comment: So what is the Problem? Please specify it.

Comment: I have already written list of the file. but still it giving me pop up to select file (with extension like .xls or all files). File name has be taken automatic from the list and open all the files at same time.

Comment: Take a look at yhe _.bat_ file contents. Based on the code snippet, it should be the _Tetradyne_ bin folder (I assume it's a folder) + a file name on the 1st line, followed by other file names on the next lines. The question is still unclear for me, but I'm sure that this batch file is not the answer.